# Using bevel profiles to create picture frames

Tags: modeling, bevel

I'm trying to use the new custom bevel option in Blender 2.82a to make picture frames.  How can I invert the custom Bevel profile to create this.  My thoughts where to use a cube and delete the faces that aren't used but how can I make the bevel be on the inside.  Is this the easiest way to do this?

[image]

The direction the bevel needs to take to mimic a frame.

[image: picture frame]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to use Bevel Weights.

1. Set the limit method to *Weight* for the *Bevel modifier*
2. Select the edges you want to bevel
3. Adjust their *Mean Bevel Weight* to 1

[image]

[image]