# How to bevel inside edge?

Tags: bevel

I'm making a recreation of a Marshall Plexi SLP1959. I've got the main outer shell done, but I have absolutely no idea how to do the bevel on the hole in the faceplate.

Here is a picture of my basic faceplate:
[image]

And here are a couple of images of the bevel I hope to achieve:
[image]
[image]

If anyone has any idea how to get this bevel I would love to know.
Thanks

Comment: Hello and welcome :). A rather similar thread here, using Bevel Weights https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/172585/